# Pull HTML data with Python - URL can ONLY be accessed via IE Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, remote-desktop

I am trying to create a Python script that can connect to the web interface of the printers in my organisation, and download the HTML of the 'Supplies' page so that I can extract data such as remaining life of components/supplies etc using BeautifulSoup (that the printer cannot automatically e-mail as an alert).

I know how to pull data from a standard public web page using Python, however here is where my challenge is.

In my organisation, in order to connect to the printer's web interface, you must first connect to the organisations WIFI.

You must then launch a Remote Desktop Connection, which upon connection, automatically opens an Internet Explorer window.

You can then access the printer's web interface from this IE window, that was spawned by the Remote Desktop Connection.

In other words, you can only access the printer's web interface through the IE window that's launched as a result of a RDC, rather than using the standard IE browser on your machine.  For this reason, Python cannot 'see/connect to' the printer web interface and my script won't work.

Would greatly appreciate any advice on how to get around this.

Thanks

Comment: You could ask the network administrator to install your script on the Windows server you are connecting to.

Comment: Thanks Marvo, I thought of that too but they won't do that.  

I was thinking more along the lines of somehow getting Python to launch the RDC (which will auto launch IE), then, somehow, getting Python to parse the printer interface URL to that IE window, and whatever HTML data is returned to that IE window, capturing it.  

Or, any other method whereby I can run the script from my own machine as this will also make it easier to test and update my code.